# Permission with the linux server using apache and php

Tags: php, linux, apache, centos

I have setup an linux CentOS 7 server to run php and i using apache, but when all done php can't write file even i have set chmod 777 and i have chown apache at the owner of the directory.

> If the file exist, i can write the data on it, but if file don't exist
>   i can create it, it notice me don't have permission (folder is chmod
>   777).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what does the apache log say ?

Comment: What's the path, what does ls -l show for the directory itself and the parents? What about getfacl? Is SELinux enabled?

Comment: I open file /var/log/httpd/error_log  and just see the notice about "PHP Warning:  fopen(vteiv/test.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied..."

Comment: Yes i have enable SELinux

Comment: And here is result when getfacl  # file: var/www/stcejorp
# owner: apache
# group: drakele
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::r-x